# Will merchants give me better prices if they like me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I saw [this page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Disposition) on disposition, it says that NPCs with more positive disposition will be nicer.

Will merchants give better prices to customers they like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.**

Prices in Skyrim are determined **entirely** by your Speechcraft skill (and any bonuses or perks therein).
Prices are computed by the following:

[From the UESP.net](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Speech#Prices)

> The Base Price Factor is calculated by your skill level (fBarterMax
>   default is 3.3, fBarterMin default is 2.0):
>
> price factor = (fBarterMax * (100 - skill) + fBarterMin * skill)/100
>
> The Modified Price Factor depends on perks and Fortify Barter bonus:
>
> sell price modifier = (1 + Haggling %) * (1 + Allure %) * (1 + Fortify
>   Barter from potion) * (1 + the sum of Fortify Barter from equipment +
>   Fortify Barter from Blessing of Zenithar)
>
> buy price modifier = (1 / (1 + Haggling %)) * (1 / (1 + Allure %)) *
>   (1 - Fortify Barter from potion) * (1 - the sum of Fortify Barter from
>   equipment - Fortify Barter from Blessing of Zenithar)
>
> The final price combines the two Price Factors and rounds to the
>   nearest whole number:
>
> sell price = ([ value of item ] / base price factor) * sell price
>   modifier buy price = [ value of item ] * base price factor * buy price
>   modifier
>
> ```
> At 0 skill and no perks, the final price factor is 3.3.
> At 100 skill and no perks, the final price factor is 2.
> At 100 skill and all perks the final price factor is 1.42857.
> Trade price cap: (max sell price = value * 1.00), (min buy price = value * 1.05).
> ```
>
> Skill levels over 100 have no effect.

Firewood and certain ores are unique in that there exist "merchants" who will exchange items for gold directly. These transactions have hardcoded numbers, and do not technically count as transactions (i.e. won't give you speechcraft xp).

Comment: So if I got to a smith and sell something and I go to another potion merchant and try to sell it I will get the exact same price.

Comment: That's what I want to know

Comment: I think that's a "no"? Should probably include a yes or no somewhere. Probably at the top.

Comment: @JimThio assuming the merchant is of the same gender, yes. There are a couple of "opposite gender" perks you can gain that give you a bonus (Allure %, in the formula above)